# Quadratic minimization with real output

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ hermitian matrix. My goal is to minimize the following hermitian form with an additionnal "real constraint":

$$\min_f f^\ast A f$$
$$\text{subject to }f \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

This optimization problem can be solved easily without the constraint $f\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (singular value decomposition).

Is there a general way to handle this problem ?
I think that the best solution could be to use a gradient-descent scheme but I do not see any reason for $f\in \mathbb{R}^n \to f^T A f \in \mathbb{R}$ to be convex.